# 'std::bad_typeid' : illegal member initialization: 'exception' is not a base or member

Tags: windows, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I am facing a weird compilation error. I created a static library and am trying to use it in another project. I am getting these errors which I just can't make sense of.

```
...\concrt.h(4878): error C3861: '__uncaught_exception': identifier not found
...\typeinfo(153): error C2504: 'exception' : base class undefined
...\typeinfo(157): error C2614: 'std::bad_cast' : illegal member initialization: 'exception' is not a base or member
...\typeinfo(174): error C2504: 'exception' : base class undefined
...\typeinfo(178): error C2614: 'std::bad_typeid' : illegal member initialization: 'exception' is not a base or member
...\concrt.h(4878): error C3861: '__uncaught_exception': identifier not found
```

They happen on files which do not use exceptions though other files in the project have instances of downcasting. Including `<exceptions>` I have RTTI and exceptions enabled in both projects. I tried disabling them in both projects without success. I even tried enabling parallel code generation as `concrt.h is` related to concurrency but that didn't change anything. Any idea what could be happening?

Comment: Are you defining `_EXCEPTION_` or `_HAS_EXCEPTIONS`?  (If so, don't.)  This has nothing to do with your static library; it's a problem with the source file you are trying to compile.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis I had _HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0 in my main project. Removing it fixed the problem. Thanks. I don't know why it was put in in the first place. I want to use exceptions because I am using `dynamic_cast` with references. Is it good practice to use this? Also, if you change your comment to answer I will mark it accepted. Thanks.

Comment: Well the presence of dynamic_casts can be an indicator for design problems (but not necessarily). In general it's good to avoid them if possible though. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5138926/594456